# Getting the base path in a Slim middleware

Tags: php, slim, slim-4

I have a Slim 4 app and I'm trying to set up a middleware that redirects non https to https. So if I type

```
this_website.com
```

in the browser, this gets redirected automatically to https://this_website.com

I have an earlier website built with Slim 3 and I could use the following:

```
final class FullHttpsMiddleware {

    public function __invoke($request, $handler) {

        $response = $handler->handle($request);

        if($request->getUri()->getScheme() !== 'https' ){

            if($request->getUri()->getPath() != '/') {
                $response = $response->withStatus(302)->withHeader('Location', 'https://' . $request->getUri()->getHost() . $request->getUri()->getBasePath() . '/' . $request->getUri()->getPath() );
            } else {
                $response = $response->withStatus(302)->withHeader('Location', 'https://' . $request->getUri()->getHost() . $request->getUri()->getBasePath() );
            }
        }

        return $response;
    }
}
```

The problem is that `$request->getUri()->getBasePath()` doesn't exist in Slim 4. How can I change this code to work on Slim 4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a blog post about this topic: [Slim 4 - HTTPS Middleware](https://odan.github.io/2020/04/07/slim4-https-middleware.html)

You could also use a `.htaccess` file to redirect the http traffic to https.

If you have existing code in your .htaccess, add the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1):

## Solution 1 (what you really should do)

Redirecting from http to https should not be done on application level, but with .htaccess.

Here is how:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

## Solution 2 (literally asked question)

You'd asked for *The problem is that $request->getUri()->getBasePath() doesn't exist in Slim 4. How can I change this code to work on Slim 4?*

### Summary

I have a `settings.php` that defines/retrieves the path settings correctly, including `$settings['root']`. I can easily access these settings then from routes, from the middleware, etc.

**Of course, you need to add your required value in the settings.php, like this_website.com**

### container.php

settings.php is included (required) from container.php:

```php
return [
    'settings' => function () {
        return require __DIR__ . '/settings.php';
    },
...
];
```

### settings.php

This is my settings.php. **Important note:** These are the values for the test environment, they **have to be changed for production**!

```php
// Should be set to 0 in production
error_reporting(E_ALL);

// Should be set to '0' in production
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

// Timezone
date_default_timezone_set('FILL_IN_YOUR_TIMEZONE');

// Settings
$settings = [];

// Path settings
$settings['root'] = dirname(__DIR__);
$settings['temp'] = $settings['root'] . '/tmp';
$settings['public'] = $settings['root'] . '/public_html';

// Error Handling Middleware settings
$settings['error'] = [

    // Should be set to false in production
    'display_error_details' => true,

    // Parameter is passed to the default ErrorHandler
    // View in rendered output by enabling the "displayErrorDetails" setting.
    // For the console and unit tests we also disable it
    'log_errors' => true,

    // Display error details in error log
    'log_error_details' => true,
];

return $settings;
```

### How to access

Now, you can access the path setting im Slim 4 with

```
$app->get('settings')
```

or, eg. when you are within a route, you have to use `$this` for `$app`, of course:

```php
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface;
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface;

$app->get('/wiki/{id:[1-9]\d*}/edit'), function (ServerRequestInterface $request, ResponseInterface $response) {
   ...
   $filename = $this->get('settings')['root'].'/src/content/wiki/edit.html';
   ...
   return (...);
});
```

`$filename` is now `/var/www` (on my system). With the adequate setting added, you can now access 'this_website.com' from your middleware.